# Django Chartit can't read @property attributes in model.Models

Tags: python, django, highcharts, properties, model

anyone know how to reference a field value in a model when it's described with the 'property' decorator?
I have an 'order' model with a property decorator which totals a number of values in fields related to my 'order' class via a foreign key.

```
@property
def total_price(self):
    """
    The total value of all items in the order, minus any discounts.
    """
    total = sum([item.total_price
                for item in self.order_orderitem_set.all()])
    discounts = sum([item.discount
                for item in self.order_orderitem_set.all()])

    return total - discountsenter code here
```

When I reference this type it's quite simple. I do:

```
myOrders = Orders.objects.all()
for key in myOrders:
   print "My total is: ", key.total_price
```

However if I use the source attribute as: Orders.objects.all and try and reference this value 'total_orders' Chartit provides me with an error that it can't find this field value.

My chartit datapool looks like:

```
    orderdata = \
    DataPool(
       series=
        [{'options': {
           'source': Order.objects.all()},
          'terms': [
            'order_date',
            'total_price']}
         ])

#Step 2: Create the Chart object
cht = Chart(
        datasource = orderdata,
        series_options =
          [{'options':{
              'type': 'line',
              'stacking': False},
            'terms':{
              'order_date': [
                'total_price']
              }}],
        chart_options =
          {'title': {
               'text': 'Total Orders Over Time'},
           'xAxis': {
                'title': {
                   'text': 'Order Date'}}})
```

I get the error:

```
Field u'total_price' does not exist. Valid lookups are promo_code, enduser_address, etc....
```

It looks like to me it is not able to reference my 'property' within the model. Is this just a limitation of the framework?

Does anyone know of a neat way of getting round this - it seems my options are:
1) Create my own json object and iterate around my 'orders' and create my own data list. Then pass this to highcharts directly; or
2) Create another table say 'OrderSaleHistory' and populate for each month via a management function that django will update periodically or from manual action. This new table will then be passed to chartit.

Or does anyone have better ideas? :-)

This is my first 'post' so quite a newbie in posting but not reading!!!!

Kind regards, Nicholas.

Comment: If your question is how do you access a model attribute created with an `@property` decorated function in `django-chartit`, the answer is: you can't currently. When you create an attribute like this, it is not actually stored in the database, and chartit uses `QuerySet`s which do come from the database. See this issue for a short explanation of why this is the case: https://github.com/chartit/django-chartit/issues/35. However, it seems like what you really want to know is *how* to plot the data which you have as `total_price` in your chart. I am not sure of the best way to do this.

Comment: Hi elethan. Thanks for your reply. OK that makes sense. And thank you for the link in github. Kind regards, Nicholas.